# How to get the column name for searched record?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have this table :

```
         mid        wid     ctitle
         ---        ---     ------
         17         5        AAA
         18         6        BBB
         24         8        CCC
         21         9        DDD
```

If I'm searching for any value, for example '5', then how I can get its column name?

If I search for '18' and it occurs in column `mid` then it should return column name as "mid".  In the case of '5' it should return 'wid'.

Is it possible using MySQL?

Comment: What is the brains behind this?. Why are you doing this?. You expect only 5 rows? If yes, why search in the first place?.

Comment: Why do you think he has only 5 rows ?

Comment: Its not what I think, its what he asked. @dystroy: Your solution does not perform a search in ctitle. Thats because you thought the search key would be "5" or "18". Do not provide a solution thats specific to an example. Probably I talked too much, but I think I make some sense and I also think you know it.

Answer (score 3):

```
select ctitle, 'mid' as which_column, mid as the_value from mytable where mid=5
union select ctitle, 'wid', wid from mytable where wid=5
```

You probably can find smarter but this should work...

(to answer to a comment, replace 5 with any other desired value if needed)